# I accidently deleted an activity.java from my com.packagename.appname. How do I get it back?

Tags: android, android-studio

While adding a feature to my app I messed up and decided to delete all the new files I had added for it but in doing that I accidentally deleted one of the activity from my app. I have integrated version control in my app and also shared my whole app source with GitHub but for some reason whenever I check out of previous version controls I cannot find the file. How can I recover the activity.java file? I have the app installed on my phone. Is it possible to recover it from there? or any other way to recover it?

Comment: Can you explain in greater detail how you tried to restore the file using Git? If it was originally added to source control you should be able to get it back.

Comment: Using version control and revert to previously saved version but it seems whatever I do the activity.java file doesn't seem to appear

Comment: Did you validate the file does exist on Github?

Comment: It doesn't but got the file in local history. thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>z</kbd> or version control didnt worked try to check the local history of the android studio:

> Move to project structure -> right click on your app name  -> local history -> show history

[image]

Comment: Worked like charm. Got all the files back

Comment: Tip for the future - when working with git better work with branches to prevent this

Answer (score 0):

Click on your package and do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> and then undo changes.

Comment: Tried it. Doesn't work. I kinda realised late that on activity was deleted then tried ctrl z but it was too late then

Comment: @Zachary how can he accept it if it isn't the answer?